# xslt concatenate text from nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, concatenation

I have an xml file that looks like this:

```
<args>
  <sometag value="abc" />
  <anothertag value="def" />
  <atag value="blah" />
</args>
```

keep in mind that tag names within args could be named anything (I don't know ahead of time)
Now i have this xml file stored in a variable called $data which I loaded using a document() call in the xslt stylesheet (its not the backing data for the xslt file)

I want to take that data and produce the following output:
**sometag=abc&anothertag=def&atag=blah**

so (a very simplified verison looks like this:

```
<xsl:template>
 <xsl:variable name="data"  select="document('/path/to/xml')" />

  <xsl:call-template name='build_string'>
    <xsl:with-param name='data' select='$data' />

  </xsl:call-template>

</xsl:template>

<!-- here is where i need help -->
<xsl:template name="build_string">
  <xsl:param name='data'>
  <xsl:value-of select='name($data/.)' />=<xsl:value-of select='$data/@value' />

  <xsl:if test='$data/following-sibling::node()'>
    <xsl:text>&#38;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:call-template name="build_str">
     <xsl:with-param name="data" select='$nodes/following-sibling::node()' />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>


</xsl:template>
```

This almost works but it also prints text nodes from the input file and I don't want to match text nodes..

Comment: Your XML is malformed. The three inner nodes should be self closing, eg `<sometag value="abc"/>`

Comment: According to the w3's xslt tool your code is a mess.

Comment: sorry my actual xslt is in a file with tons of other stuff going on, i wrote this by hand in the editor stack overflow so its probaby got errors in it..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*/*">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(name(),'=',@value)"/>

  <xsl:if test="not(position()=last())">
    <xsl:text>&amp;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<args>
  <sometag value="abc"/>
  <anothertag value="def"/>
  <atag value="blah"/>
</args>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
sometag=abc&anothertag=def&atag=blah
```

Comment: How would I do this if I had data in a variable which I wanted to make into a string

Comment: @Matt: THis is not clear -- you need to update your question and to show exactly what is contained in the `$data` variable. Depending on this unknown information the answer may be different.

Comment: the $data variable holds the 
<args>

Comment: @Matt: change the template match attribute to `match="args/*"`, probably add a `mode="build-string"`, and then from another template, `<xsl:apply-templates select="$args/*" mode="build-string"/>`.

Comment: @Matt: just `<xsl:apply-templates select="$data/*"/>`

Comment: Oh ok i see what you did there

Answer (score 3):

I ended up realizing I could just use a for-each loop..
I'm not sure why I didnt use that to begin with. I'm still wondering how I could recursively iterate a list of adjacent nodes the way I was doing before (which wasn't working correctly because it was also catching text nodes and doing other weird things I couldn't understand).
Here is my solution (I also added a separator variable)

```
<xsl:template name='string_builder'>
    <xsl:param name='data' />
    <xsl:param name='separator' />        
    <xsl:for-each select='$data/*'>
        <xsl:value-of select='name()'/>=<xsl:value-of select='@value'/>
        <xsl:if test='position() != last()'>
           <xsl:value-of select='$separator'/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: the reason your recursive implementation was catching text nodes was because you passed the data parameter as `$nodes/following-sibling::node()` instead of `$data[1]/following-sibling::*`. The `*` matches only elements, while `node()` matches text nodes and others too. Better would be `$data[position() != 1]`, if $data contains only the child elements of the args element.

Comment: Just going over old questions I asked and saw your comment. I am sorry @DimitreNovatchev that I did not accept your answer. The reason being was that it didn't fit my xslt structure and required more work than what I have shown above. I simply wanted to take a variable holding a node set (from document function), and convert it to a string as shown, which yours didn't do.. It used the backing document of the xslt. Your fix for how to use that with my code was more work then what I solved it with.

Comment: xsl:apply-templates is ok in some cases, but when you want to do some  procedural logic, which would in most programming languages mean call a function, you break the readability.. If i used apply-templates all over I have to do reverse searches to figure out what the hell is being done to my xml.. IMO it makes a huge clusterf*ck of code.

Comment: say what you will about my understanding of xslt. I know you are the guru but I spent several months on a project trying to use xslt the preferred way using lots of help from you and others on here (thank you by the way). Eventually most of that I ditched and came up with my own method of applying xslt to construct html pages.. Which now works very similar, and has many features of MVC frameworks I am fond of such as Ruby on Rails and Symfony PHP (Specifically the feature is called slots in Symfony). I did a lot of research on how people used xslt and found it to be very verbose and not DRY

Comment: @MattWolfe: Why not share your approach (say in a blog)? This would be interesting. Even a single example where use of templates is inferior to your methodology would be appreciated. Mayby it isn't just "use of templates" but more specifically your own understanding and usage of them.

Comment: I actually started writing a blog yesterday for this but my blog's syntaxhighlighter is messed up..Haven't used it in 2 years or so and did all the drupal updates yesterday and now <br> tags are showing on each new line of the syntaxhighlighter output. I will post it though. I think XSLT has some really cool features and I like how it's agnostic as to what technology you use (well, you need to use xml but you can do that from anything). It seems that perhaps with 2.0 it may have been a lot more useful but unfortunately microsoft doesn't support it with .net so we had no choice.

Comment: alright got the syntax highlighter working again.. I will work on it and try and best explain the problem/solution.

Comment: @MattWolfe: Any news -- two months later?